# Classify up to similarity all the matrices A $\in Q^{3 \times 3}$ such that $A^3$ = I

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the minimal polynomial $p_A$ must divide $(x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$ since $A^3 - I = 0$.

If $p_A$ = (x - 1), then A = I.

If $p_A = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$, then $p_A$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial, since it is of degree three. Hence, $Q^3$ has an A-cyclic vector, and A is similar to the companion matrix \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0 & 1  \\
   1       & 0 & 0   \\
   0       & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}

What can I say about the case if  $p_A =(x^2 + x + 1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
 The minimal polynomial $p_A(x)$ is a divisor of $x^3-1$, so it is either $x-1$ or $x^2+x+1$ or $x^3-1$
Now the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial  have the *same* irreducible  factors, so:

- if $p_A(x)=x-1$, $\chi_A(x)=(x-1)^3$ (the matrix is $I$);
- the case $p_A(x)=x^2+x+1$ cannot happen, since $\chi_A(x)$ should be a power of $p_A(x)$ of degree $3$
- if $p_A(x)=x^3-1$, it is equal to $\chi_A(x)$, and the matrix is diagonalisable over $\mathbf C$.

Comment: how do you know that's the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Because it has degree $3$, and the matrix has dimension $3$ and it is  an annihilator polynomial.

Comment: ok, i see. but if the minimal polynomial must be equal to x^3 - 1, then doesn't that mean A cannot be I? which is clearly possible?

Comment: You're right, I was a little too fast, and supposed the matrix wasdiagonalisable  over $\mathbf C$. I'll to think a little about it.

Comment: ok, i follow the updated comment, and i think it correctly answers the case when p = x^2 + x + 1. however, i don't think that if p_A = X_A thne A is diagonalizable, since the min polynomial is not the product of distinct linear factors

Comment: The matrix is diagonalisable *over* $\mathbf C$, not over $\mathbf Q$, of course. As I explain in my updated answer, the case $p_A(x)=x^2+x+1$ cannot happen. So the characteristic polynomial is either $(x-1)^3$ or $x^3-1$.